# avcodec_open2 error -542398533 : "Generic error in an external library"

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am encountering an error when trying to open the codec with `avcodec_open2()`. I have tried the same code without any problems if I specify `avi` instead of `h264` in the `av_guess_format()` function.

I don't know what to make of it. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

The library that I'm using is **ffmpeg-20160219-git-98a0053-win32-dev**. I would really really appreciate if you could help me out of this confusion.

This is my console output:

> Video encoding
>    [libx264 @ 01383460] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
>    [libx264 @ 01383460] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
>    [libx264 @ 01383460] preset usage: -vpre  -vpre 
>    [libx264 @ 01383460] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
>    [libx264 @ 01383460] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
>    Cannot open video codec, -542398533

This is the code that I'm working with:

```
// Video encoding sample
AVCodec *codec = NULL;
AVCodecContext *codecCtx= NULL;
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
AVOutputFormat *pOutFormat = NULL;
AVStream * pVideoStream = NULL;;
AVFrame *picture = NULL;;

int i, x, y, ret;

printf("Video encoding\n");

// Register all formats and codecs
av_register_all();

// guess format from file extension
pOutFormat = av_guess_format("h264", NULL, NULL);
if (NULL==pOutFormat){
    cerr << "Could not guess output format" << endl;
    return -1;
}   

// allocate context
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
pFormatCtx->oformat = pOutFormat;
memcpy(pFormatCtx->filename,filename,
    min(strlen(filename), sizeof(pFormatCtx->filename)));

// Add stream to pFormatCtx
pVideoStream = avformat_new_stream(pFormatCtx, 0);
if (!pVideoStream) 
{
    printf("Cannot add new video stream\n");
    return -1;
}

// Set stream's codec context
codecCtx = pVideoStream->codec;
codecCtx->codec_id = (AVCodecID)pOutFormat->video_codec;
codecCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
codecCtx->frame_number = 0;
// Put sample parameters.
codecCtx->bit_rate = 2000000;
// Resolution must be a multiple of two.
codecCtx->width  = 320;
codecCtx->height = 240;
codecCtx->time_base.den = 10;
codecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
pVideoStream->time_base.den = 10;
pVideoStream->time_base.num = 1;
codecCtx->gop_size = 12; // emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most
codecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

if (codecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
{
    // Just for testing, we also add B frames 
    codecCtx->mb_decision = 2;
}
// Some formats want stream headers to be separate.
if(pFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
{
    codecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

if(codecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
    av_opt_set(codecCtx->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);


// Open the codec.
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecCtx->codec_id);
if (codec == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
    return -1;
}
ret = avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL); // returns -542398533 here
if (ret < 0) 
{
    printf("Cannot open video codec, %d\n",ret);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

> `codecCtx = pVideoStream->codec;`

This `AVCodecContext` was allocated using global defaults, which x264 rejects because they are not optimal. Instead, use [`avcodec_alloc_context3`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#gae80afec6f26df6607eaacf39b561c315) to allocate it, which will set x264-specific defaults. At the end of your encoding, don't forget to [`avcodec_free_context`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#gaf869d0829ed607cec3a4a02a1c7026b3) the returned pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean I need to allocate a new `AVCodecContext` and copy that to replace the `codec` member in `pVideoStream`?

Comment: No replacement necessary, simply ignore the one in pVideoStream.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting an access violation at avcodec_encode_video2, but I'll do some search before posting again.

Comment: Turns out I cannot ignore `pVideoStream->codec`, because `width and `height` is 0 in `pFormatCtx->streams[0]->codec`. Ignoring it caused an Access Violation error. I'll post my next question or solution here, whichever comes first.

Comment: Hm, I had not thought of that. I guess you can use the newly allocated context as your "master" and (after initializing it etc.) use avcodec_copy_context() to fill in the pVideoStream->codec one from the master.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass codec param to avformat_new_stream

```
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecCtx->codec_id);
    pVideoStream = avformat_new_stream(pFormatCtx, codec);
```